# How can I specify what PassportJS does after a callback without using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

The PassportJS website has the following code example, where somebody can specify their own flow of logic after a callback goes through:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

However, I am not using Express, and am finding it very difficult to replicate the above behavior.

Here is my current code that deals with facebook authentication callbacks:

```
if(path == '/auth/facebook/callback'){
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/failbook', 'successRedirect':'/success'})(req, res, next);
        return;
}
```

I have no idea how to change it so that I can alter the flow of logic post-callback. I'd like to be able to check some variables that I have saved and redirect to different locations accordingly. Any thoughts on how I can go about doing this?

Also - on a related note - if I'm just refreshing the facebook access token (AKA if it has expired and I'm getting a new one), is it possible to not redirect the user anywhere at all, so that their browser doesn't go to a different page at any point in time during the refreshing process (which involves a re-authentication with facebook)?

Answer (score 0):

check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/passportjs/HTG13e2pb74
its a group which uses passport with node "vanilla"